# Unable to install geojson package for R

Tags: 16.04, package-management, paths, r, pkg-config

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and R 3.4.3. When I run

```r
install.packages("geojson", dep=TRUE)
```

in R, I get the following error:

> dependency ‘protolite’ is not available for package ‘geojson’

Therefore I run

```r
install.packages("protolite", dep=TRUE)
```

to which I get:

```
Configuration failed because protobuf was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libprotobuf-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: protobuf-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
 * csw: protobuf_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: protobuf (OSX)
If protobuf is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a protobuf.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
```

However, running `protoc --version` in terminal I get

```
libprotoc 2.6.1
```

So it seems I have the latest version installed. I also tried copying `protobuf.pc` in `/usr/lib/pkconfig/` and setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` with

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

with no success. I don't know how to check if `pkg-config` is in my
`PATH`, nor how to follow the latter manual instructions. In particular, I don't know what directories I should write for `INCLUDE_DIR=...` and `LIB_DIR=...`.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Did you install the `libprotobuf-dev` packages as suggested in the second error message? Or do you have and would like to use a different instance of that library?

Comment: yes, it tells me it is already the newest version

Comment: What's the output of `pkg-config --modversion --cflags --libs protobuf`?

Comment: { Ignoring incompatible output option "--cflags"
Ignoring incompatible output option "--libs"
2.6.1 }

Comment: Huh? That's very odd. What's the output of `which pkg-config`, `pkg-config --version` and `apt-cache policy pkg-config pkgconf`?

Comment: /usr/bin/pkg-config
/usr/bin/apt-cache
/usr/bin/pkg-config

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73887/discussion-between-nicu-righeriu-and-david-foerster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install your R packages with the following actions

```
#1. add R 3.4.3 repository if not added before
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
EOF

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9

#2. add repository for libjq-dev
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:opencpu/jq

#3. update package lists
sudo apt-get update

#4. install R and dependencies
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev r-base-core libjq-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
libssl-dev libprotobuf-dev libjq-dev libv8-3.14-dev protobuf-compiler

#5. launch R and install geojson package:
R
> install.packages("geojson", dep=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found that my `/usr/bin/pkg-config` (version 0.29.1 bundled with Ubuntu 18.04) is ultra-buggy. It doesn't look into directories mentioned in PKG_CONFIG_PATH (custom directories were not seen in  debug spew). I had to build newer version (0.29.2) from source. This solved my issue.

Hope it helps someone